# How to run a webphar PHP file from built-in PHP 5.4 webserver?

Tags: php, php-5.4, phar

As per title, I created a very simple test phar. I'd like to test it with the built-in webserver(PHP 5.4) but it seems impossible.

```
php -S localhost:80 /path/to/myphar.php
```

<s>Result: blank page (in the phar front controller is `index.php` doing some HTML output).</s>

```
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/folder_with_index_and_phar
```

With loader script:

```
<?php

require 'phar://myphar.php'
```

Result in a blank page, again.

Is this even possible or I have to use Apache?

**EDIT**: after an year I need this again. Here is what's happening (from answers):

```
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/app.phar
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/app.phar
```

Results in an error: /path/to/app.phar is not a directory.

While:

```
php -S localhost:80 -t .
http://localost/app.phar/foo/bar
```

Works, but **I don't need the app.phar** "prefix"!

Using Apache and setting the directory index to app.phar works as expected.

Comment: Do you get errors from the loader script option, perhaps in your logs?

Comment: Pherhaps there are some grammar errors in your `myphar.php`. What happen if you excute `echo "<?php phpinfo();" > myphar.php`

Comment: check this https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1004 hope it helps atleast a bit :)

Answer (score 5):

`php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/phar` isn't going to work since the `-t` argument is meant to be used for directories. The trick is that the php webserver supports passing a router as argument. Therefore, suppose your phar is in /tmp (it can be anywhere), this is how you create a simple router, and setup the webserver:

```
echo '<?php require("/path/to/phar");'>/tmp/router.php
php -S localhost:80 /tmp/router.php
```

Answer (score 5):

```
php -S localhost:8080 phpinfo.phar
```

That seemed to work for me just fine from a simple phar file I created to out put `phpinfo();`

I did notice in the PHP docs, when creating the PHAR file, that you seem to need to setup stubs for CLI and WWW interfaces.

http://php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromdirectory.php

```
<?php
// create with alias "project.phar"
$phar = new Phar('project.phar', 0, 'project.phar');
// add all files in the project
$phar->buildFromDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/project');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('cli/index.php', 'www/index.php'));
```

**EDIT**

Specifically, this is what I did.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$phar = new Phar('phpinfo.phar', 0, 'phpinfo.phar');

$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__ . '/phpinfo');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('index.php'));
```

to create a phar file of a directory:

```
phpinfo/
└── index.php
```

and index.php was just:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 3):

After hours of messing around with built-in web server, finally found the solution to what you are looking for. The key is router file for the web server. Follow below procedure

1) Create a router.php file for built-in web server with following content

```
    $path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if($pathPosition = strpos($path,'/myapp') !== false){
        //Request has been made to Phar-ed application
        $pathPosition += strlen('/myapp');
        $file = substr($path, $pathPosition);

        //Here include the base path of your Phar-ed application with file path
        //I placed myphar.phar and router.php in the root directory for this example
        require_once("phar://myphar.phar/$file");
        exit;
    }
    return FALSE;
```

What this does: It checks the Uri for your application name, in my case "/myapp" and then extract the file path you want to access. Then includes the desired phared file into current script and exits. Else process the request as normal.

2) Start the built-in web server as follows:

```
     php -S localhost:80 -t . router.php
```

What this does: Fires up the built-in webserver making current directory as document root folder and uses router.php as router file (Placed in the same folder)

3) Make a request in browser like this:

```
    http://localhost/myapp/foo/bar
```

You will get the Phar-ed file from you application .phar file

Let me know in case of questions.

Note: You can also use regex to match the Uri pattern in router.php

Answer (score 2):

So, I do not understand why you need the Apache server. After the command

`php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/myphar.php`

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 Development Server started at Fri Jun  6 22:27:49 2014
Listening on http://localhost:80
Document root is /tmp/http
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

means all is well, you go to your browser's address bar write

```
http://localhost:80
```

and see the result of the script execution

Comment: Sorry for answering so late but this won't work: webserver says: /path/to/myphar.php is not a directory!

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to be a bit more flexible you could do what you want by creating an `index.php` file and then including your `.phar` which is possible [according to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php) which states that:

> Using a Phar archive library is identical to using any other PHP library:

Therefore you can just include it normally like such:

```
<?php require_once "app.phar";
```

After you run `php -S localhost:80` the index.php will be executed and you can just access it via `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

On windows if you are using xampp serve then you can use this command in command line.

```
C:\xampp\php>"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\php\pharcommand.phar"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an index.php file in the same directory as that app.phar. the contents of it should be :

```
<?php
require "myapp.phar";
?>
```

Then access it by serving that index.php file using the command `php -S localhost:80 /path/to/pharapp/index.php`

Answer (score -1):

You can run a webphar with the built in web server by renaming the phar to have a `.php` extension (e.g. `mv app.phar app.php`), pointing to that directory:

```
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/phar
```

and accessing it as `http://localhost/app.php/someroute.php`. The tricky part is usually [setting up the stub](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.webphar.php), [munging the environment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.mungserver.php), and [generating the phar](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs48.html).

Comment: Sorry for answering so late but this won't work: webserver says: /path/to/myphar.php is not a directory!

Comment: @gremo Make sure "-t /path/to/phar" is only pointing to the directory _containing_ the phar, not the phar itself (e.g., NOT "/path/to/phar/myphar.php"). If you are running this command in the same directory as the phar you can leave the "-t" bit off.